# Button submit Form HTML double action (submit and reload)

Tags: html, reload, submit-button

I have the following html that the button does a normal Save:

```
<form action="" method="post">    
    <input type="hidden" value="{{ people }}" name="people">
    <input type="hidden" value="{{ number }}" name="number">
    <p>{% trans 'Are you sure you want to save people' %} {{ people }} {% trans 'where number is' %} {{ number }}?
    </p>

    {% buttons %}
        <button class="btn btn-default hover-linea" id="cancel" type="button">
            {% bootstrap_icon "remove" %} {% trans 'Cancel' %}
        </button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default hover-linea">
             {% bootstrap_icon "log-out" %} {% trans 'Save' %}
        </button>
        {% endbuttons %}
```

What I need when I do the Save, is to reload the previous page to the form. I want to press Save and do the same as now, but also make a location.reload() of a page whose relative link is (../people.html).

I await an answer, thank you very much.

Comment: I await still a pink unicorn .... so how does your button now operate in js, or what ever language you use to proces this?

Answer (score 0):

Your server-side form handler (which you have specified the URL to in your `action`) attribute should respond with an HTTP redirect (status `302` and the `Location:` header) to the URL you want the browser to load.